# vlc media player plays audio for 18 seconds, then stops for a split second, then continues playing the audio

Tags: audio, vlc-media-player

The problem: VLC media player version 3.0.18 plays audio for 18 seconds, then stops playing audio for a split second, then continues playing the audio.

(It is on a Windows 10 machine playing a flac file that is on my hard disk.)

I tried over a hundred "solutions" from all over the web and from all over this site. Nothing helped.

Can anybody tell me what is causing this?

THE ONLY TEMPORARY SOLUTION up to now: I installed the previous version, version 3.0.17.

You can download 3.0.17 here: https://www.videolan.org/vlc/releases/3.0.17.html (at that Videolan page: scroll down near bottom).

No more audio that stops for a brief second. Problem thouroughly solved. Let's hope for a better update than 3.0.18, so uncheck the VLC player's update box until there's a proper follow up for the present crappy 3.0.18 version.

(First fully uninstall the present VLC-media player.)(Include preferences!). Install the previous version, the update question comes directly after installing. You can also find the update settings here: Tools - Preferences - [] Activate updates notifier (near the bottom in the tab "Interface"). Uncheck the box [] if it's not yet unchecked.

I know, this way you will lack whatever "improvements" of version 3.0.18, but I consider a glitch in the audio worth while reverting to the previous version...

Again: Can anybody tell me what is causing the audio error in version 3.0.18 ? In other way: can you explain why version 3.0.17 plays audio correctly and version 3.0.18 does not?

Comment: Does it affect all files, or just that one, or just flac? BTW, you telling us you 'tried 100 solutions' tells us absolutely nothing at all.

Comment: +1 for explaining an issue I've also noticed -- I'll revert from VideoLAN archives, http://download.videolan.org/pub/videolan/vlc/

Comment: Try the new nightly build 3.0.19 and see if it's already been fixed: https://artifacts.videolan.org/vlc-3.0/nightly-win64/20230126-0220/ . If not, consider reporting the bug to vlc: https://code.videolan.org/videolan/vlc/-/issues/

Comment: to Tetsujin - it affects all of my flac files (they all are being played flawlessly on MS Mediaplayer and Foobar and Audacity) - I tried all "solutions" on this site and on many other sites, indeed over a hundred "solutions", and if that is telling nothing at all: imagine for several weeks you tried over a hundred "solutions": does that tell enough?

Comment: to Cpt.Whale: the videolan site only offers me 3.0.18 for a download

Comment: The link provided by Cpt. Whale is for the *nightly* version, the bleeding edge "beta" or probably *alpha*. It currently offers 3.0.19 so I don't understand the point of your last comment other than show that you DIDN'T open the provided link.

Comment: to Cpt.Whale: I am DEFINITELY not going to switch to an unstable version. Videolan says: "Warning! The nightly builds are UNSTABLE and may not work at all. There is absolutely NO SUPPORT for it from the VideoLAN Team."

Comment: No-ONE is telling you to switch. The whole point is to TRY and see if the problem is already solved or not. If it is you can keep using it, sooner than later that will be the stable version. If not solved and while it isn't then you may downgrade (link already provided) -and- please report the bug. No-one here can give you a solution for the current version therefore those are your only solutions, end of story.

Comment: to ChanganAuto: again: unstable version, unsupported version, no way that I'm gonna even try that. End of story.